# How to improve my question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, deleted-questions

My question ([10k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335006/using-javascript-instead-of-perl)/[non-10k](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16335006/edit)) has been removed for reasons of moderation.

It seems that I had a precise question. Perl is known to be a perfect fit for a number of applications (which I enumerated). Can Javascript handle these applications just as well?

Was there a way to rephrase my question, or was it fundamentally flawed?

Comment: Downvoted again?? I'm going to open another "how to improve this question" for this one :-P

Comment: [Voting works differently on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Answer (score 11):

It was fundamentally flawed.

The reason being that the answer is very subjective; subject to opinion.

One person might say Perl is the best; another might say JS is the best.

It therefore does not have *one* "correct" answer, and is not constructive:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will **likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion**.

You can also see from [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask):

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, **avoid asking subjective questions where**…
>
> - **every answer is equally valid**: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”

Comment: Why is is subjective? I'm not asking if JS is better than Perl. I could have rephrased my question like this: Can JS send SQL queries to a DB? can Javascript read and manipulate files on a file system? Can JS be run standalone, and not via a browser?

Comment: Anyways, I found some answers in another question. No need to waist everyone's time on this question. Cheers

Comment: Personally, like you, I've never used Perl. So I'd be inclined to say JS is the "best" for this. That said, somebody who likes Perl might say the same thing, vice versa. Rephrasing your question to more specific questions is good, but not like that. Don't just ask yes/no questions.